# C++ Boost Graph: How to customize callback function vf2_print_callback in vf2_subgrap_iso.hpp

Tags: c++, boost, callback

## Background:

I am using `boost::vf2_subgraph_iso(graph1, graph2, callback)` in [vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp).
In [sample](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/graph/example/vf2_sub_graph_iso_multi_example.cpp) provided by `boost`, they used `boost::vf2_print_callback<graph_type, graph_type> callback(graph1, graph2)` to print vertex pair to terminal.

## What I've done:

I want to customize the callback function so that once `boost::vf2_subgraph_iso(graph1, graph2, callback)` called it will make a call to my callback function. The reason I want to customize callback function is that I want to store vertex pair in vector rather than printing them in terminal.

Below is my work so far:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

template <typename Graph1,
            typename Graph2>
class my_call_back {

public:
    // constructor
    my_call_back(const Graph1& graph1, const Graph2& graph2) : graph1_(graph1), graph2_(graph2) {}

    template <typename CorrespondenceMap1To2, typename CorrespondenceMap2To1>
    bool operator()(CorrespondenceMap1To2 f, CorrespondenceMap2To1) {

        BGL_FORALL_VERTICES_T(v, graph1_, Graph1)
            vertex_iso_map.push_back(std::make_pair( get(boost::vertex_index_t(), graph1_, v) , get(boost::vertex_index_t(), graph2_, get(f, v))));
            set_of_vertex_iso_map.push_back(vertex_iso_map);
            vertex_iso_map.clear();

        return true;
    }
    std::vector <std::vector <std::pair<int, int>>> get_setvmap() { return set_of_vertex_iso_map; }

private:
    const Graph1& graph1_;
    const Graph2& graph2_;
    std::vector <std::vector <std::pair<int, int>>> set_of_vertex_iso_map;
    std::vector <std::pair<int, int>> vertex_iso_map;   
};

int main()
{
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS> GraphType;

    std::ifstream dot_small("small.dot");
    std::ifstream dot_large("large.dot");
    std::ofstream subgraph_iso_output("large1.dot");

    GraphType graph_small, graph_large;
    boost::dynamic_properties dp(boost::ignore_other_properties);

    boost::read_graphviz(dot_small, graph_small, dp);
    boost::read_graphviz(dot_large, graph_large, dp);

    my_call_back<GraphType, GraphType> callback(graph_small, graph_large);
    boost::vf2_subgraph_iso(graph_small, graph_large, callback);

    // get vector from callback
    auto set_of_vertex_iso_map = callback.get_setvmap();

    // output vector size here
    std::cout << set_of_vertex_iso_map.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto set_of_v : set_of_vertex_iso_map)
    {
        for (auto v : set_of_v)
            std::cout << "(" << v.first << ", " << v.second << ")" << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    boost::write_graphviz(subgraph_iso_output, graph_small);

    return 0;
}
```

## My Problem:

After calling `boost::vf2_subgraph_iso` function, I decide to get vector from object `callback`. But it seems like the vector is always empty. I think there is something to do with `BGL_FORALL_VERTICES_T` macro defined in [iteration_macros.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/graph/iteration_macros.hpp), but when I look at it I can't find any clue. I was guessing: Maybe callback called by `vf2_subgraph_iso` function makes new `my_callback` object and destroy it when function is done. But how can the function makes new `my_callback` object? I don't understand. And how can I fix it? (Right now I can only set vector as global variable to make it work, which is a horrible choice)

Comment: It's not exactly the same case, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440501/visitor-class-holding-large-shared-state-best-way-to-implement-reference-semant) is related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

```
bool operator()(CorrespondenceMap1To2 f, CorrespondenceMap2To1) {

    BGL_FORALL_VERTICES_T(v, graph1_, Graph1)
        vertex_iso_map.push_back(std::make_pair( get(boost::vertex_index_t(), graph1_, v) , get(boost::vertex_index_t(), graph2_, get(f, v))));
        set_of_vertex_iso_map.push_back(vertex_iso_map);
        vertex_iso_map.clear();

    return true;
}
```

At least fix the formatting to express the intent:

```
bool operator()(CorrespondenceMap1To2 f, CorrespondenceMap2To1) {

    BGL_FORALL_VERTICES_T(v, graph1_, Graph1) {
        vertex_iso_map.emplace_back(get(boost::vertex_index_t(), graph1_, v), get(boost::vertex_index_t(), graph2_, get(f, v)));
    }
    set_of_vertex_iso_map.push_back(vertex_iso_map);
    vertex_iso_map.clear();

    return true;
}
```

And the real issue is:

```
boost::vf2_subgraph_iso(graph_small, graph_large, callback);
```

Passes `callback` by value, acting on copies! Pass by reference:

```
boost::vf2_subgraph_iso(graph_small, graph_large, std::ref(callback));
```

Comment: wow this works like charm! So what `boost::vf2_subgraph_iso` did is copy `callback` object so my vector doesn't change, right?

Comment: @NeelBasu that's surprising. Maybe boost's `reference_wrapper` doesn't have https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator()